# How do I get my computer's fully qualified domain name in Python?

Tags: python, networking, dns, subdomain

I know I can use platform.node() to get my computer's network name:

```
>>> import platform
>>> platform.node()
'MyComputerName'
```

But what I really want is something that will work similar to the following:

```
>>> get_full_network_domain_name()
'MyComputerName.it.na.mycompany.com'
```

Does something like this exist?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The fully qualified domain name is returned by [`socket.getfqdn()`](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.getfqdn).

Comment: Thanks, "fully qualified domain name" was the phrase I was looking for!

Comment: For me this doesn't yield the same result as `hostname -f` on the shell. So be careful.

Comment: @DaniëlvanEeden , do you know what is the situation it does not return the same as in `hostname -f`?

Comment: @semente , `hostname -f` does it like this: `socket.getaddrinfo(socket.gethostname(), 0, flags=socket.AI_CANONNAME)[0][3]` and `getfqdn()` seems to lookup the hostname in /etc/hosts and uses the first entry which contains a dot. For me the `hostname -f` returns 'daniel-thinkpad' and `getfqdn()` returns localhost6.localdomain6

Comment: @DaniëlvanEeden: Thanks! However, my version of `getaddrinfo` doesn't support keyword arguments, so I had to use `socket.getaddrinfo(socket.gethostname(), 0, 0, 0, 0, socket.AI_CANONNAME)[0][3]` instead.

Comment: This does not work reliably at all. Half the time it comes back with just the hostname when I see that the hostname it comes back with is easily looked up by nslookup and comes back with an fqdn.

Comment: A scenario I'm running into gives an incorrect result with either option (`getfqdn()` or the more elaborate function call from @DaniëlvanEeden).  My scenario is when I have my Windows 10 "work" laptop, connected to my home WiFi.  The laptop's normal FQDN is along the lines of `laptopname.big.company.network.com`, and this is what both methods return.  But on my home network, the laptop's actual working FQDN is just `laptopname.lan`.  Neither of the commands above return this.