# How can I get the default machine domain name in Python using a portable way?

Tags: python, dns

I am looking for a Python solution for obtaining the current machine default domain name, one that will work on Linux, Mac OS X and Windows.

So far I discovered that:

- Linux has `dnsdomainname` which returns it

Comment: Have you tried the solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580023/how-do-i-get-my-computers-fully-qualified-domain-name-in-python)?

Comment: Also try [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271740/how-can-i-use-python-to-get-the-system-hostname)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket

def get_dns_domain():
    return socket.getfqdn().split('.', 1)[1]

print (get_dns_domain()) # to match python>2.7
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
from socket import gethostname
machine_name=gethostname()
print(machine_name)
```