# Python: FQDN like `hostname --fqdn`?

Tags: python, fqdn

The fully qualified domain name is returned by [`socket.getfqdn()`](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.getfqdn).

BUT: it does not do the same as "hostname --fqdn".

There are some hints in the comments of the following question, but I would like to know the canonical answer. [How do I get my computer's fully qualified domain name in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580023/how-do-i-get-my-computers-fully-qualified-domain-name-in-python)

How to get the FQDN like `hostname --fqdn` does.

Answer (score 4):

To put it all together:

Python3:

```python
import socket

socket.getaddrinfo(socket.gethostname(), 0, flags=socket.AI_CANONNAME)[0][3]
```

Python2:

```python
import socket

socket.getaddrinfo(socket.gethostname(), 0, 0, 0, 0, socket.AI_CANONNAME)[0][3]
```

Credits:
[How do I get my computer's fully qualified domain name in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580023/how-do-i-get-my-computers-fully-qualified-domain-name-in-python/11580042#comment38763823_11580042)